# Why is the write() method writing the same amount of data with each iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

**Here's the output:**

[image: The output as you can see, the direct download links are different but still it writes the same amount of data i.e. 38781 bytes]

**Here's the code:**

```
#Write downloaded data 
    for x in range(len(direct_links)):
        #print("Writing file : {}".format(direct_links[x]))
        with open("{}.rar".format(x+1),'wb') as fw:
            print("After writing file : {}".format(direct_links[x]))
            data = c.get(direct_links[x])
            flag = fw.write(data.content)
            print("Downloaded {} of data of {}".format(flag, results_text[x]))
```

So here, `direct_links` is a list which contains direct download links to attachments on a website. Now, `c.get(direct_links[x])` puts the response in the variable `data` and the variable `flag` stores the bytes of data written to my file. Now my question is why does the write function write only 38781 bytes of data for each iteration even if the direct download links download data of different sizes and obviously the downloaded data is corrupt.

Comment: _"the direct download links download data of different sizes and obviously the downloaded data is corrupt"_ I see no evidence that this is the case.

Comment: I don't know what types are involved here but read https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write

Comment: Inferentially it has to be right? I mean look at the links in the output, they're all different attachments.

Comment: Don't just assume that because they have different IDs, they _must_ be of different lengths. Actually find out whether that is the case.

Comment: If I manually visit those direct download links that are outputted, of course they contain data of different sizes. And before the code I've pasted above, I have opened a session on that website, scraped all the results from a particular webpage and then scraped the URLs of the results to get those direct download links which are available only I maintain that session. So yes all direct download links are definitely getting scraped and stored in my list as you can see in the ouput. Still I'll try to determine the "data" variable in the above code. Thanks for your quick replies!

Comment: Okay then put that proof in the question as part of your [MCVE] please

Comment: Ah thanks for your help, but I think the issue might be visible in the output links itself. I mean the links aren't direct links to the file according to me, even though we can download the files if we click on any of the links in my list. So for each write operation I was performing, only the response is getting written. That's my hypothesis, your input on it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The response for most large file downloads is a 206 Partial Content response. Usually you are expected to download large files in chunks, so that if you disconnect during download you can resume from the first chunk you are missing. That's why browsers are able to implement pause and resume functionality for large downloads.

Comment: If that is the case for the files you're downloading, you'll need to send many requests to download a single file, specifying the offset you want to start at in HTTP header. If you have 38781 bytes of the file after the first request, you should specify an offset of of 38781 for the next chunk and continue until you have the entire file.

Comment: But each file is mostly under 1 MB. All of the file sizes are in KBs.